# How to write variable argument logger function which does actual logging in c++

Tags: c++, logging

i am writing a logger class in c++ i want to redirect all the logs from different files to a function which decides where to write the log.

for example,

```
func A()
{
int a =10;
std::string b = "test";
cout<<"printing"<<a<<b<<endl;
}

func B()
{
unsigned long t = 6700;
cout<<t<<endl;
}
```

Instead of cout i want to have a function which takes variable arguments and sent to common function which finally prints or writes into a file or used syslog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you tried something simple, like this?

```
std::unique_ptr<std::ostream> g_ostream_ptr;


std::ostream& log() {
    return *g_ostream_ptr;
}

void initialize_log() { 
    // initialize `g_ostream_ptr` based on environment variable
    // or other configuration information.
    const char* filename = std::getenv("LOG_FILE");
    if (!filename)
        filename = "/dev/stdout"

    g_ostream_ptr = std::make_unique<std::ostream>(filename);
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
void f() {
    log() << “f called.” << std::endl;
}
```

You would have to ensure that `initialize_log`is called at some point, perhaps using `std::call_once`, or perhaps by simply calling it in `main()`.

Comment: Actually i dont want to mention the file path in the initialise, i might have to write the same log in 2 different outputs like syslog and a file. So if i can somehow redirect it to a single function which can write it into multiple files it would be helpful